# How to make location variable in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, location, variant

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\**VARIANT**\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx")
```

I want to make the "variant" part a variable dependent on input. I want to do that because it needs to be revised for every other user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Environ$` to get the current user:

```
Dim desktop As String
desktop = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"
Debug.Print desktop
```

Comment: Just a note, the actual command is `Environ` the `$` is a [type hint](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables#t=201608031318332236455)

Comment: @litelite - No, it's actually a different function entirely. `Environ` is an alias for `_B_var_Environ` and returns a `Variant`.  `Environ$` is an alias for `_B_str_Environ` and returns a `String`.

Comment: Oh yeah just saw the doc. The notation is quite confusing tough.

Answer (score 2):

### Reference: [Special Folders](http://ss64.com/vb/special.html)

```
FilePath = getDeskTopPath & "\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx"

If Len(Dir(FilePath)) > 0 then

    Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

End If
```

---

```
Function getDeskTopPath()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim strPath As String

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    getDeskTopPath = strPath

    Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

---

You can also have use the Application.FileDialog to choose a file or folder. See this artice for details: [VBA FILEDIALOG – OPENING, SELECTING AND SAVING FILES AND FOLDERS](http://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/)

Comment: this the proper way to find the Desktop location. On most of the corporate machines you will hardly find the Desktop hosted on local root. +1

Comment: ^^^Agreed and upvoted.  I was actually going to edit this into my answer but I had to drive to work.  ;-)

Comment: I already gave your answer the +1.  It cuts straight to the chase.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim variablePart as String

variablePart = "someFolderName"

Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & variablePart & "\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx")

'will lead to: C:\Users\someFolderName\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx")
```

Comment: at first i was thinking like this but it gives syntax error

Comment: at location part it gives 1004

Comment: location part? do you mean `Workbooks.Open`? If so, try it without the brackets: `Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & variablePart & "\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code below:

```
Sub InsertUserName()

Dim folder_var  As String

folder_var = InputBox("Insert your User Name")

Workbooks.Open ("C:\" & folder_var & " \Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\Data_BCT.xlsx")


End Sub
```

Comment: at first i was thinking like this but it gives syntax error